# Where is the mention of Surya Loka(सूर्य लोकं) in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, surya

One of the famous stotras for Lord Surya in Hinduism is [श्रीसूर्याष्टकम्](https://omshivam.wordpress.com/ayurveda-knowlwdge-of-life/surya-namaskar/surya-ashtakam/) (Surya ashtakam). In the last line of this सूर्याष्टकम्, there is a mention of **Surya Loka**.

> स्त्रीतैलमधुमांसानि ये त्यजन्ति रवेर्दिने । न व्याधि शोक दारिद्र्यं
>   सूर्य लोकं च गच्छति ॥११॥

Meaning: He who ceases from intimate company of women, oil bath, meat, honey on Sunday, will not be affected by miseries caused due to diseases, worries or poverty and shall live happily; at the end He will depart (directly) to Sūryaloka – the abode of Lord Sūrya.

So it seems that Sūryaloka is the abode of Lord Sūrya.

According to [An Analysis of the Brahma Sutra](http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/brahma/brahma_05.html) by Swami Krishnananda, it is mentioned that

> Highly purified souls travel through the rays of the sun to the orb of
>   the sun. The rays of the sun are the paths through which the soul
>   travels higher and reaches the Sun. In order to go to the sun, the
>   soul has to be as bright, as powerful, as pure as the Sun. The soul
>   gets purified in Surya Loka (Solar Region).

**My Question is** : Which Hindu scriptures describe in detail about the Sūryaloka? Is there any mention of any interesting story leading to the formation of Sūryaloka ?

Comment: It could mean 'Manipur Chakra' which is solar region of our body... or Pingala nadi which is also a solar nadi... but this just my guess...

Comment: @Tezz While reading the An Analysis of the Brahma Sutra, it is mentioned that Highly purified souls travel through the rays of the sun to the orb of the sun. The rays of the sun are the paths through which the soul travels higher and reaches the Sun. In order to go to the sun, the soul has to be as bright, as powerful, as pure as the Sun. The soul gets purified in Surya Loka (Solar Region). This is why I posted this Q to get more info about such important place called Surya loka

Comment: @WhisperingMonk I think "madhu" is alcohol not honey.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Oh..it could be. I just copy-pasted the translation from the web site, hence its not my own knowledge of language. please feel free to edit the post to make it correct linguistically,

Comment: @The Destroyer no, madhu means honey... Diabetes is called 'Madhumeha'... sugar/sweet disease... 'Madhya' means alcohol... taking alcohol is called madhyapaan...

Comment: @Tezz See [Why is madhu (honey) considered a prohibited food in brahmacharya?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10999/3500)

Comment: @The Destroyer oh then it could mean both honey and alcohol...

Comment: Similar post : [Want to know about Brahma Loka](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12400/277)