# What is Paramapadam? Is it different from Vaikunta?

Tags: vaishnavism, vaikuntha

Can someone please elaborate what is Paramapadam and where it is? Are Vaikunta and Paramapadam one and the same?

Comment: Related: [What is the “param dhama” that Lord Krishna refers to in Bhagavadgita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16882/277)

Comment: it's just another name for Vaikuṇṭha